# How does it possible two hardware RAIDs in lsblk but one - in lspci?

Tags: linux, raid, lsblk

lspci output:

```
Slot:   02:00.0
Class:  RAID bus controller
Vendor: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic
Device: MegaRAID SAS 2208 [Thunderbolt]
SVendor:        Dell
SDevice:        PERC H710P Mini (for monolithics)
Rev:    01
```

lsblk output:

```
NAME MODEL              SIZE ROTA
sda  PERC H710P       446.6G    1
sdb  PERC H710P        10.9T    1
```

what does it mean?

Comment: It looks like `lspci` is showing you the RAID controller, which is apparently exporting two logical drives (which is what you see in `lsblk`). The two commands are showing you different things.

Comment: Yeah, my first thought was the same. The misunderstanding is caused by the fact that usually lsblk shows the logical parts obviously